# Java installer with added libraries

Tags: java, installation, rxtx

I am very new to Java (first-year student). I tried searching for similar questions but can't find anything that exactly meets my needs. I am trying to figure out how to create a JRE installer for Windows that includes additional files beyond the standard libraries. In particular, I am trying to use files from this source: http://jlog.org/rxtx-win.html. I want the RXTXSerial.dll file to go into the "bin" folder, and the rxtxcomm.jar file to go into the "lib\ext" folder.

Ideally, this would be used by a user who isn't good with computers at all, so that all they would have to do is run the JRE installer, and already have the necessary RXTX files needed to run an external application (that I unfortunately don't have any control over).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at install4j...

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you should be able to control what JRE/libs are deployed with your application using this.

Comment: I'm checking it out now. It looks promising. I'm not wanting to deploy the files with an application, but rather the files with the JRE installation, but this looks like it can do both. Thanks.